# Are cigarette lighters allowed in airports?

Tags: airports, airport-security, smoking

In India and South Korea the airports have smoking rooms. It's a nice convenience for people who feel like they have to smoke every so often but it makes me wonder...  how do people light up in those rooms?

Are they able to bring cigarette lighters passed the security check point? Are they able to buy them once their inside the secure area? Or maybe the smoking rooms have built-in cigarette lighters in the same way cars do?

I guess I could have gone in and asked but I don't smoke and thought the smell would get to me and didn't want to loiter around when I had a flight to catch.

Comment: I bought a Cigarette lighter in Wroclaw, Poland in their own airport. The lighter didn't even have fluid in it. When I got to Frankfurt, Germany I was asked to step out of line to quickly find out I was under suspicion because of this fluidless lighter. I was asked by a group of guards where I got it (it had the Polish flag on it with the word "Polska"), do I smoke (I don't) and why I was hiding it in my jacket (which i wasn't intentionally, just had it there). Germans must not like Polish lighters. That's just my lighter experience. which btw, Frankfurt and Munich both had these smoking rooms

Comment: Whether or not it's allowed depends on what country you're in. This is too broad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Standard cigarette lighters are generally allowed in carry-on baggage.  Obviously this is an area where exact regulations vary from country-to-country, and there may be limits on the maximum number per person (eg, 1!) but for the most part they are allowed.

For example, the US TSA "Can I Take" website will give you the [requirements for cigarette lighters](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/items/disposable-and-zippo-lighters) when passing through US airports.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the **[Can I Bring](http://apps.tsa.dhs.gov/mytsa/cib_home.aspx)** website.

Answer (score 2):

At the airports of Uganda, Rwanda, Tanzania and nowadays also in Kenya, they search for lighters and matches. It is not allowed to carry any whether it is in check in baggage, in the hand luggage or in your pocket. They will take it!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Doc's answer, some smoking rooms at airports have cigarette lighters in them as well. You may check [this website](http://www.ciglow.co.uk/) for the product information on such lighters.

I believe this ensures that you do not require a cigarette lighter in your baggage to smoke in permitted smoking areas in airports such as Delhi,Frankfurt or Amsterdam as these airports usually have such services installed at the airport.

Answer (score -1):

I never had a problem with cheap plastic lighters.  I would put them in the xray bin and it would be fine.